# How do I pass a JavaScript class instance to DOM Event Listener?

Tags: javascript, dom, object

I have what seems to be a very tricky situation. I would like to pass an instance of an object to the event listener of a DOM element that was created by that same object instance (if that makes sense).

```
function Object(callback){
    this.callback = callback;
    this.node = document.createElement('div');
    this.send = function(){
        document.getElementById('list').appendChild(this.node);
    }
    this.node.addEventListener('click',function(){/*this.callback() of Object instance needs to go here*/},true);
}
```

I know that using `callback()` would work inside the event listener, but thats not what I need because I will be using variables from the instance that are not passed from the construct later on.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The anonymous function changes the meaning of *this*.  To be able to use it within the handler, use another var, or don't create another function:

```
var elem = this;
this.node.addEventListener('click',function(){ elem.callback(); },true);
```

or

```
this.node.addEventListener('click', this.callback, true);
```

Comment: One more question, does elem get evaluated at definition only or again when the event fires? If not when the event fires is there any way to do that?

Comment: It only gets evaluated when the outer function is evaluated.  elem is stored to be used when the callback is fired, but it will always refer to the same instance; If you change the instance in the meantime, elem will reflect the changes (there is only ever one instance, it is not copied, elem just becomes another reference to it).  I can't see a reason why you would need the assignment to run again when the event fires.